# Why won't a nested scrollview respond to scrolls in swiftUI?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I'm building an SwiftUI app with a dropdown menu with a vertical ScrollView within another vertical ScrollView. However, the dropdown menu one (the nested one) won't scroll. I would like to give it priority somehow. It seems like a simple problem, but I have scoured the internet but cannot find an adequate solution. Here is the basic code for the problem (the code is cleaner in the app but copy and pasting particular snippets did not work very well):

```
    ScrollView{
    VStack{
        (other stuff)
        DropdownSelector()
        (other stuff)
}
}

struct DropdownSelector(){
ScrollView{
VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 0) {
            ForEach(self.options, id: \.self) { option in
                (do things with the option)
            }
}
}
```

Comment: If it is already within a ScrollView, why nest them? Even if it did work, it seems like it would lead to UX issues.

Comment: @jnpdx Basically I'm making a form and I want the dropdown menu (which has a lot of options and due to the nature of the app will usually not be used) to be its own section and not part of the larger scrolling of the form.

Comment: With that being said it does seem to lead to UX issues haha. Is there a better way to get the desired effect without nesting?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Creating nested `ScrollView`s in the first place is probably a bad idea. Nonetheless, there is a solution.

Because with `ScrollView` it scrolls as much as the content height, this is a problem when they are nested. This is because the inner `ScrollView` isn't limited in height (because the outer `ScrollView` height just changes), so it acts as if it wasn't there at all.

Here is a minimal example demonstrating the problem, just for comparison:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            VStack {
                Text("Top view")

                DropdownSelector()

                Text("Bottom view")
            }
        }
    }
}

struct DropdownSelector: View {
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 0) {
                ForEach(0 ..< 10) { i in
                    Text("Item: \(i)")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

To fix it, limit the height of the inner scroll view. Add this after `DropdownSelector()`:

```
.frame(height: 100)
```

[image: Result]